# Como pushear datos en un array vacio cada que vez que una funcion en disparada

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy intentando guardar un valor random en un array cada vez que un usuario hace click en un botón pero el valor solo permanece en el mismo en el momento de la ejecución de la función.

```
let boton = document.getElementById('boton');
boton.addEventListener("click", iniciar);

let numeroRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

let secuencia = [];

function iniciarluz(valor){

  let elementos = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  elementos[valor-1].className = "prendida";
  secuencia.push(valor);
}

function iniciar(){
  iniciarluz(numeroRandom);
}
```

Comment: Si quieres que el valor cambie cada vez que hagas click, deberas introducir su sentencia de declaracion dentro de la llamada que haces al hacer click.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que poner el numero random dentro de la funcion.  De la manera que lo tienes, lo asignas una sola vez.

```js
let boton = document.getElementById('boton');
boton.addEventListener("click", iniciar);

let secuencia = [];

function iniciarluz(valor){

let elementos = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
elementos[valor-1].className = "prendida";
secuencia.push(valor);
console.log(valor);
}

function iniciar(){
let numeroRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
iniciarluz(numeroRandom);
}
```

```css
.prendida {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="boton">Boton</button>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```